Why doesn't this SIMD code show better performance?
I wrote a simple code to test the performance and set my data:
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime> 
#include <smmintrin.h>
#include <immintrin.h>

unsigned t0, t1;

struct VAL
{
    union
    {
        float   val[4];
        __m128  val_simd;
    };
};


int main()
{
    unsigned t0, t1;
    double time;
    VAL *a, *b, *c;
    unsigned test_num = 100000000;

    a = new VAL[test_num];
    b = new VAL[test_num];
    c = new VAL[test_num];
    
    t0 = clock();
    for (int i = 0; i < test_num; i++)
    {
        a[i].val[0] = static_cast <float> (rand()) / static_cast <float> (RAND_MAX);
        a[i].val[1] = static_cast <float> (rand()) / static_cast <float> (RAND_MAX);
        a[i].val[2] = static_cast <float> (rand()) / static_cast <float> (RAND_MAX);
        a[i].val[3] = static_cast <float> (rand()) / static_cast <float> (RAND_MAX);
        b[i].val[0] = static_cast <float> (rand()) / static_cast <float> (RAND_MAX);
        b[i].val[1] = static_cast <float> (rand()) / static_cast <float> (RAND_MAX);
        b[i].val[2] = static_cast <float> (rand()) / static_cast <float> (RAND_MAX);
        b[i].val[3] = static_cast <float> (rand()) / static_cast <float> (RAND_MAX);
        c[i].val[0] = 0.0f;
        c[i].val[1] = 0.0f;
        c[i].val[2] = 0.0f;
        c[i].val[3] = 0.0f;
    }
    t1 = clock();
    time = (double(t1 - t0) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC);
    std::cout << "Execution Time0: " << time << '\n';

    t0 = clock();
    for (int i = 0; i < test_num; i++)
    {
        c[i].val[0] = a[i].val[0] + b[i].val[0];
        c[i].val[1] = a[i].val[1] + b[i].val[1];
        c[i].val[2] = a[i].val[2] + b[i].val[2];
        //c[i].val[3] = a[i].val[3] + b[i].val[3];
    }
    t1 = clock();
    time = (double(t1 - t0) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC);
    std::cout << "Execution Time1: " << time << '\n';

    t0 = clock();
    for (int i = 0; i < test_num; i++)
    {
        c[i].val_simd = _mm_add_ps(a[i].val_simd, b[i].val_simd);
    }
    t1 = clock();
    time = (double(t1 - t0) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC);
    std::cout << "Execution Time2: " << time << '\n';

    delete[] a;
    delete[] b;
    delete[] c;
}

...however running the code does not give me superior performance as I should expect.
I expected to see much better performance, at least 3x the performance, however this gave the same times. On the other hand, testing the same code but multiplying SIMD gave me but performance.
The configuration used was:
/permissive- /ifcOutput "x64\Release\" /GS /GL /W3 /Gy /Zc:wchar_t /Zi /Gm- /O2 /sdl /Fd"x64\Release\vc143.pdb" /Zc:inline /fp:precise /D "NDEBUG" /D "_CONSOLE" /D "_UNICODE" /D "UNICODE" /errorReport:prompt /WX- /Zc:forScope /Gd /Oi /MD /openmp /FC /Fa"x64\Release\" /EHsc /nologo /Fo"x64\Release\" /Fp"x64\Release\TEST1.pch" /diagnostics:column 

the results (for a Intel(R) Xeon(R) E-2276M  CPU @ 2.80GHz, Memory 32,0 GB, Windows 11 Pro for Workstations) were:
Execution Time0: 11.498
Execution Time1: 0.264
Execution Time2: 0.232


You might check the resulting assembly code -- maybe the compiler is being clever and generating SIMD code for your non-SIMD loop as well?

You're throwing around 5GB of data.  You might be memory-limited.

In general it is very hard to beat compilers nowadays. The compiler too will vectorize code if it can, AND it will use all the knowledge it has on pipelining/out of order execution etc to rearrange the assembly statements for an optimal result.

@TimRoberts You mean memory bandwidth limited right?

@OP when doing performance tests you should build with optimization flags enabled, and you should not be using inline time measurements. You really should be using a profiler, a profiler  will show you where your real bottlenecks are (cache misses, memory fetching, branch prediction misses etc..). Only that way you can add any meaning to the timings you see.

What are your actual time results?  What compiler version and build options, running on what CPU model?  With c[i].val[3] = ... commented out, it could still auto-vectorize with AVX1 vmaskmovps stores, although IDK if any compiler would do that.  Or as others pointed out, even pure scalar code can may be able to saturate single-core memory bandwidth (2x addss per clock, and on Ice Lake and later, 2 stores per clock).  Actually all the work should be optimized away because you don't use the results; clang at least understands new / delete.

The actual numbers would tell us a lot about what might be happening, like if they've both a handful of microseconds then it's just timing overhead as expected from the work optimizing away.  See also Idiomatic way of performance evaluation?

https://godbolt.org/z/x4eKbGahv - clang -O3 does indeed optimize away the loops other than init.  We just get call    clock@PLT / mov     rbx, rax / call    clock@PLT.  GCC -O3 on the other hand does some insane auto-vectorization with a ton of shuffling, perhaps trying to use all 4 or 8 elements of every vaddps instead of just accepting one empty lane.  And/or because it needs to avoid storing to c[i].val[3], and doesn't use a masked store for that. (They're slow on AMD, but it still does this with -march=skylake).  GCC's asm for the intrinsic loop is as expected.

675 / 5.000
Thank you very much for your response, I will try to understand what you told me since the truth is that I am a mechanical engineer and the most technical part of programming is a bit difficult for me, since the programming that I took for the development of simulation software DEM, I have programmed all my code in a vectorized way for CPU, multi CPU and even CUDA and everything has worked, I also generated the visualization in OPENCL.

But this last thing about SIMD is newer to me. But now I wanted to see if implementing my Vector x, y, z, taking it to 128bit float x, y, z, w, float val[4] and __m128 val_simd, I would gain processing time even if it increased my memory cost by 25%.

The scalar loop takes 675 seconds, the _mm_add_ps loop takes 5 seconds?  That doesn't make much sense either.  [edit] your question with more details, including build options and what compiler version/options on what CPU and OS.

I updated the question, thanks for helping

Ok, so you're using MSVC since those look like MSVC options.  https://godbolt.org/z/c3MKPjK7d shows it doesn't optimize away the loops even though the results are unused.  (I removed most of your compile options other than -O2 since some of them overrode Godbolt's options that make it produce an asm listing, and I didn't know which did what.)  It just unrolls some.  Might well be bottlenecked on memory bandwidth.

5GiB / 0.264 seconds = 18.9 GiB/s which is nearly half the theoretical max DRAM controller bandwidth on your Coffee Lake (https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/192989/intel-xeon-e-2276m-processor-12m-cache-2-80-ghz.html assuming dual-channel DDR4-2666), and it's normal for a single core not to saturate it, especially with a mix of read and write.  5GiB / 0.232 seconds = 21.6 GiB/s so 128-bit SIMD is a bit faster.  Your CPU supports AVX2, but I wouldn't expect 256-bit SIMD (_mm256_add_ps) to be more than a tiny bit faster.
